# How to "override" semantic token type of VSCode theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to know how to tweak my VSCode theme (One Dark Pro), a theme with semantic highlighting.

I cannot override some of its semantic token types.

With most themes I would write this in settings.json:

```
{
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "name": "Javascript - Variable/object",
        "scope": [
          "variable.other.object.js"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#c7452e",
          "fontStyle": "bold italic"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But with this theme (and also other ones with semantic opinion) I cannot override it, as if I needed to use `!important` in CSS.

So this is the result of my token and scope inspection after my rule.

[image]

As you can see, my settings are indeed read but are apparently not 'specific' enough as to beat the semantic interpretation or overridden by it, and are disregarded (last three lines) and instead the modifying semantic token type takes prevalence.

Is there a way to do this per individual textmate scope (i.e. without losing the rest of the semantics of that wonderful theme) like if I just want to change the color of that particular item?

Comment: This was reported as an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92627#issuecomment-601600921) in March 2020, but it was closed because "Semantic highlighting wins against syntax highlighting as the semantic token provider has a better understanding of the source than the regex based TextMate grammar", even though the semantic tokens are less specific than the TextMate grammars...

Answer (score 0):

So when syntax is highlighted by a theme, `settings.json` files have priority over the syntax highlighting implemented by your set theme, however, if you activate semantic highlighting, then the theme highlights your syntax, your settings.json file takes priority & overrides the theme, and then the language server has priority over the theme and over the local user, & workspace, `settings.json` files. So in other words, you can't override the token because the token is being overridden already by a scope that has higher priority than your configuration file. Now with that said, if you don't like it, just turn Semantic highlighting off (code snippet below shows the configuration for turning off semantic highlighting).

```
    /** @file "./.vscode/settings.json" */

    {
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false
    }
```

Comment: If it doesn't help (as for me) try language specific config:
"[javascript]": {
  "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false
},

Comment: @GeorgiyBukharov You shouldn't have to specify the language. The ability to configure settings that way is not to get a configuration to work via a work around, but rather to support different  configurations across different file-types. Configuring `[javascript]` to not use semanticHighlighting should work just as well as simply setting `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled":` to _**false**_. If your having to do it that way, its likely do to an over polluted user (or WSL if your using WSL) `settings.json` file. `settings.json` can be configured at a variety of different scopes, which

Comment: can also cause confusion, and settings to act in ways that can be troublesome & hard to figure out.

Comment: Taking your comments into account I need to add that in case if you already have some language specific settings general `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false` won't work with that language, you need to add `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false` into that language settings.

Comment: **Semantic Highlighting** is the coloring of syntax that is defined by a language server. The _semantic highlighting_ colors over the highlighting that done through TextMate tokens, therefore, if you arnt using a language server that supports semantic highlighting, it just won't do anything. The only reason to turn semantic highlighting off is if you don't like how the semantic highlighting, highlights your code. Which is typically in the case of a theme that has been developed in a way that doesn't account for language servers. Cont...

Comment: Semantic Highlighting needs to be taken into consideration by theme developers, but that is often not the case. The just choose to turn it off, and develop there theme with TextMate tokens because it is easier, however, there is certain highlighting that cannot be achieved without the use of **Semantic Tokens**. Please note, Semantic Highlighting doesn't ever not work with a language. Its just a theme-quality, and preference thing.

Comment: Well, whatever, but reality is so: `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false` doesn't work, `"[javascript]": { "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false }` works.